# Symfony: How to show first Route in the address bar accessing by second one

Tags: php, symfony

I have a controller with two routes:

```
/**
*@Route("/first", name="important_route")
*@Route("/second")
**/
public function index() {
    return new Response("Hi");
}
```

But I need when a user access using "/second" route, the browser address bar show "/first". Actually already I did it, but I'm not sure if is the best way.

**My solution:**
I created a new controller:

```
/**
*@Route("/second")
**/
public function redirectToIndex() {
    return $this->redirectToRoute("first");
}
```

Then I removed the second route in the original controller:

```
/**
*@Route("/first", name="important_route")
**/
public function index() {
    return new Response("Hi");
}
```

Comment: So /second is just an alias without different content? Indeed, then redirection is the way to go since it prevents duplicate content as well.

Comment: That's right, there is no different content, because I'm using "/second" as a shorten link. Please consider something as: "/first" and "/fst".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new controller:

```
/**
*@Route("/second")
**/
public function redirectToIndex() {
    return $this->redirectToRoute("first");
}
```

Then remove the second route in the original controller:

```
/**
*@Route("/first", name="important_route")
**/
public function index() {
    return new Response("Hi");
}
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? Just posting code does not enable the OP (and others) to learn from it

Answer (score 0):

You have already solved your problem. If you need user to see the `/first` in browser's address bar you need to do redirects.

But redirects can be set up in web-server level and in application level. You do redirect in the application. This way is more flexible because you have access to database but not optimal for server resource usage.

Second way to redirect user is to set up redirect rule in your web-server. This way depends on the web-server you use, and you have no access to database. This way useful when you want to "cache" your routes and not to launch Symfony application every time user requests page by shorten link.

Comment: Thank you, understanding the theoretical part of my solution is also important.